# How to pass different parameters to a function that updates different tables using their respective sqlalchemy orm classes?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, orm, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy orm, I have different classes for different tables in a database. Here are for example two of them:

```
class PortfolioDim(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'portfoliodim'

    Id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    PortfolioId = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True)
    CompositeFrenchName = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True)
    StartDate = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    EndDate = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    Benchmark = sa.Column(sa.String)
    ClientOrFundName = sa.Column(sa.String) 
    LastUpdated = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)


class ValueFact(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'valuefact'

    Id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    PortfolioId = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True)
    Date = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, index=True)
    Currency = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True)
    OpeningValue = sa.Column(sa.Float)
    ClosingValue = sa.Column(sa.Float)
    CashFlow = sa.Column(sa.Float)

    LastUpdated = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, index=True)
```

So far, I wrote 2 different functions to update each of them. Respectively:

```
def update_valuefact(connecstr, dropindic, filedata):
   ''' Update value fact table, where filedata 
        is a list of rows, using sqlalchemy orm 

   '''

    dbsession.init_db(connecstr, dropindic, 
        tableclassunderfocus=ValueFact)

    session = dbsession.create_session()

    for row in filedata:  
        valeur = ValueFact(CashFlow=row[0],
        ClosingValue= row[1],
        Currency= row[2],
        Date = row[3],
        OpeningValue= row[4],
        PortfolioId = row[5]
        )

        session.add(valeur)

    session.commit()



def update_portfoliodim(connecstr, dropindic, filedata):
    ''' Update portfolio dimension table, 
    where filedata is a list of rows, using sqlalchemy orm 

    '''

    dbsession.init_db(connecstr, dropindic, 
           tableclassunderfocus=PortfolioDim)

    session = dbsession.create_session()

    for row in filedata:  

        portefeuille = PortfolioDim(Benchmark= row[0],
        ClientOrFundName = row[1],
        CompositeFrenchName=row[2],
        EndDate = row[3],
        PortfolioId= row[4],
        StartDate= row[5]
        )

        session.add(portefeuille)

    session.commit()
```

Assuming database expands, I'd like to write a single update_table function. I was thinking I could pass it a dictionary listing the various fields in the various tables, such as:

```
tablefieldsdicos = {'portfoliodim': {'PortfolioId': 'str', 'CompositeFrenchName': 'str',
                            'StartDate': 'datetime', 'EndDate': 'datetime', 'ClientOrFundName': 'str',
                            'Benchmark': 'str'},
                    'valuefact': {'CashFlow': 'float', 'Currency': 'str', 
                            'ClosingValue': 'float',
                            'Date': 'datetime', 'OpeningValue': 'float', 'PortfolioId': 'str'}}

def update_table(connecstr, dropindic, filedata, tableclassunderfocus,
                tablefieldsdico):

    ''' update a single table
    filedata: list of rows (loaded from a csv file)
    tableclassunderfocus: class matching table in sa orm
    tablefieldsdico: dictionary where the keys are the name of the fields in alphabetical order
    (order matching the order of the columns in source file "filedata")

    '''

    dbsession.init_db(connecstr, dropindic, tableclassunderfocus)

    session = dbsession.create_session()

    colindices = []
    fields = []

    for k, field in enumerate(tablefieldsdico.keys()):
        colindices.append(k)
        fields.append(field)

    for row in filedata:  
        portefeuille = tableclassunderfocus(Benchmark= row[0],
        ClientOrFundName = row[1],
        CompositeFrenchName=row[2],
        EndDate = row[3],
        PortfolioId= row[4],
        StartDate= row[5]
        )

        session.add(portefeuille)

    session.commit()
```

I wonder how to pass the lists fields and colindices as arguments to the class pointed to by tableunderfocus. The items in fields should replace here Benchmark, ClientOrFundName, ..., StartDate, but the fields would be different (and the length of the field list would be different) for a different class / table. The items in colindices should replace the indices in row[*].

Any suggestions to solve this? Including an entire different way to write such a function, maybe?

Comment: Given your latter `dict` approach, it looks a bit like you're basically re-implementing `Session.bulk_insert_mappings()`, though maybe I've misunderstood the form of the data.

Comment: Thanks, Ilja, for pointing out this function. This solved it, as documented in Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a list of dictionaries where the keys are the table fields and the values are the elements from a row in data source file.
Then pass that list of dictionaries to sqlalchemy bulk_insert_mappings function, as pointed out by Ilja's comment.

```
def update_table(connecstr, dropindic, filedata, tableclassunderfocus, tablename):
    ''' update a single table
    filedata: list of dictionaries
     (1 dictionary: keys are table fields; values are elements in source data rows (e.g. loaded from a csv file))
    tableclassunderfocus: class matching table in sa orm
    tablename: name of table in db    
    '''

    dbsession.init_db(True, connecstr, dropindic, tableclassunderfocus)

    session = dbsession.create_session()

    session.bulk_insert_mappings(tableclassunderfocus, filedata)

    session.commit()
```